# Dont want particular row to be displayed in powershell

Tags: powershell, html, csv

Dont want row to be displayed.

```
$out= "C:\temp\DD2.html"
$css = @'
<style>
* {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
'@

[string]$html = Import-Csv "C:\Users.csv" | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $css | Out-File $out
```

Comment: Try `Import-Csv "C:\Users.csv" | Where-Object ($_.Parameter -ne "Windows" -and $_.Parameter -ne "Antivirus") | ConvertTo-Html...` to filter out Windows and Antivirus

Comment: Then you're running it against a file that has something different than the sample you posted.

Comment: Thanks @squillman It's resolved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users.csv" | Where-Object ($_.Parameter -ne "Windows" -and $_.Parameter -ne "Antivirus") | ConvertTo-Html...
```